# Why list comprehensions create a function internally?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, cpython, python-internals, dis

This is disassembly of a list comprehension in [python-3.10](/questions/tagged/python-3.10):

```py
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> dis.dis("[True for _ in ()]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fea68e0dc60, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (())
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7fea68e0dc60, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (_)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

From what I understand it creates a code object called `listcomp` which does the actual iteration and return the result list, and immediately call it.
I can't figure out the need to create a separate function to execute this job. Is this kind of an optimization trick?

Comment: Comprehensions have their own scope for the loop control variable as if a function. See [link](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) for explanation and discussion of the background to this.

Comment: Extremely closely related question (from back in Py 2 when listcomps *didn't* do this, but genexprs, setcomps and dictcomps *did*): [Why do generator expressions and dict/set comprehensions in Python 2 use a nested function unlike list comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26500330/364696)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The main logic of creating a function is to [isolate the comprehension’s iteration variable](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/)<sup>peps.python.org</sup>.

By creating a function:

> Comprehension iteration variables remain **isolated** and don’t overwrite
> a variable of the same name in the outer scope, nor are they visible
> after the comprehension

However, this is *inefficient at runtime*. Due to this reason, [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12) implemented an optimization called [comprehension inlining(PEP 709)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-709-comprehension-inlining)<sup>peps.python.org</sup> which will no longer [create a separate code object](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/#specification)<sup>peps.python.org</sup>.

> Dictionary, list, and set comprehensions are now inlined, **rather than
> creating a new single-use function object for each execution of the
> comprehension.** This **speeds up execution of a comprehension by up to
> two times**. See *PEP 709* for further details.

Here is the output for the same code disassembled with [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12):

```
>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> dis.dis("[True for _ in ()]")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (())
              4 GET_ITER
              6 LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR      0 (_)
              8 SWAP                     2
             10 BUILD_LIST               0
             12 SWAP                     2
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 26)
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (_)
             20 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             24 JUMP_BACKWARD            6 (to 14)
        >>   26 END_FOR
             28 SWAP                     2
             30 STORE_FAST               0 (_)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   34 SWAP                     2
             36 POP_TOP
             38 SWAP                     2
             40 STORE_FAST               0 (_)
             42 RERAISE                  0
ExceptionTable:
  10 to 26 -> 34 [2]
```

As you can see, there is no longer a `MAKE_FUNCTION` opcode nor a separate *code object.* Instead [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12) uses [`LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR)<sup>docs.python.org</sup>(at offset `6`) and `STORE_FAST`(at offset `30`) opcodes to provide the isolation for the iteration variable.

Quoting from the [*Specification* section](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/#specification)<sup>peps.python.org</sup> of the PEP 709:

> Isolation of the `x` iteration variable is achieved by the combination
> of the new `LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR` opcode at offset `6`, which saves any
> outer value of `x` on the stack before running the comprehension, and `30`
> `STORE_FAST`, which restores the outer value of `x` (if any) after running
> the comprehension.

In addition to that, in [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12) [*there is no longer a separate frame for the comprehension in tracebacks*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-709-comprehension-inlining).

| Traceback in <[python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12) | Traceback in [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12) |
| --- | --- |
| ``` >>> [1 / 0 for i in range(10)] Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero ``` | ``` >>> [1 / 0 for i in range(10)] Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero ``` |

And here is the [benchmark results](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/#reference-implementation)<sup>peps.python.org</sup>(measured with MacOS M2):

```
$ python3.10 -m pyperf timeit -s 'l = [1]' '[x for x in l]'
Mean +- std dev: 108 ns +- 3 ns
$ python3.12 -m pyperf timeit -s 'l = [1]' '[x for x in l]'
Mean +- std dev: 60.9 ns +- 0.3 ns
```

Comment: Does that mean they will leak variables into the outer scope after that PEP? Or is it inlining them without interacting that way?

Comment: @fyrepenguin No it won't leak the variables. See the [`Specification` section to understand how PEP 709 provide the isolation for the iteration variable](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/#specification). Also please note that this PEP introduces few visible behavior changes which is listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-709-comprehension-inlining)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I see the `LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR` is the new opcode responsible for that. Neat

Comment: Every day I am surprised at how inefficiently python does some things.

Comment: Put another way, Python 3 mandated that the variable not leak. Defining an anonymous function was the CPython *implementation* of this mandate, until Python 3.12, at which point the implementation, not the mandate, changed.

Answer (score -4):

List comprehensions in Python don't create a function internally. They are a concise way to create lists. If you're referring to lambda functions, they can be used within a list comprehension to apply a function to each element. However, list comprehensions themselves are not functions; they're a syntactic construct for creating lists.

Comment: They're a syntactic construct for creating `list`s that, prior to 3.12, *used a function internally*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

list comprehensions in Python do not create a function internally. List comprehensions are a syntactic construct for creating lists in a concise and readable manner. They are not equivalent to creating or using functions, and they do not involve the creation of functions behind the scenes.

List comprehensions are more closely related to loops, as they provide a compact way to express a loop that constructs a list. They are a shorthand notation for creating lists and are evaluated in a single line. Here's an example to illustrate:

```
# Using a for loop to create a new list
```

original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = []
for item in original_list:
new_list.append(item * 2)

## Equivalent list comprehension

new_list_comprehension = [item * 2 for item in original_list]

print(new_list)  # Output: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
print(new_list_comprehension)  # Output: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

In the example above, the list comprehension [item * 2 for item in original_list] is a concise way to achieve the same result as the for loop without explicitly creating a separate function.

To reiterate, list comprehensions are not functions; they are a specific syntax for creating lists. Functions, on the other hand, are defined using the def keyword and involve a more general mechanism for encapsulating reusable blocks of code.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?